# PostgreSQL array decorator

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I realized that there are two ways to indicate arrays in a table in PostgreSQL but I cannot figure out what the difference is, or if either one has any advantages.

There seem to be two syntaxes:

- {a,b,c,d,e}
- [0:4]={a,b,c,d,e}

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
     (id serial, arrayspalte smallint[], dt timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO table1
     (id, arrayspalte, dt)
VALUES
     (330, '[0:4]={12,14,27,45,50}', '2007-09-30 10:39:52'),
     (331, '{2, 6,100,200,500,1000}', '2007-09-30 10:41:52')

;
```

Which in the table then looks like this:
[image]

Both an array, but both look very different. It's clear that the former one shows the dimensions of the array, but is there any bigger difference between the two? And is it OK to have  both kinds in the same table, or could that cause issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the array lower bound is 1:

```
select ('{12,14,27,45,50}'::int[])[5];
 int4 
------
   50
```

You changed the lower bound to zero:

```
select ('[0:4]={12,14,27,45,50}'::int[])[5];
 int4 
------

(1 row)
```

In your example the first element of the second array can not be returned at `[0]`

```
select
    coalesce(a[0]::text, 'null'),
    array_lower(a, 1),
    array_upper(a, 1)
from (values
    ('[0:4]={12,14,27,45,50}'::int[]),
    ('{2, 6,100,200,500,1000}')
) s(a)
;
 coalesce | array_lower | array_upper 
----------+-------------+-------------
 12       |           0 |           4
 null     |           1 |           6
```

Comment: So, it is all about changing the array's bounds; good to know. So, it would *not be wrong* to use both kinds in the same table but it would most likely not be advised, as the query would return unexpected results, right?

Comment: Unexpected as in unexpected for those, who used both when defining the arrays and who are now surprised why the 'indexig does not work'.

Comment: @BritishSteel I'm unaware of a use case for the decorator. But it must be somewhere in the mailing list.